# How can I automatically manage auto-generated config files via Git between mobile and desktop Obsidian?

Tags: git, github, cross-platform, obsidian

I've recently set up a GitHub-hosted repository that manages an [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md) vault folder, including the `.obsidian` config folder. Using the [Obsidian Git](https://github.com/denolehov/obsidian-git) plugin (and MGit on mobile), I can now sync my notes *and* plugins between my computer and phone. However, there is a problem: due to the way the mobile app handles plugins it doesn't support, two config files in the `.obsidian` folder—`core-plugins.json` and `community-plugins.json`, which list the active plugins—are changed *automatically* by the mobile app upon opening, marking any unsupported plugins as disabled (i.e. removing them from the list).

Ideally, I would like any changes I make to my **desktop** configuration (including to the config) to be reflected in the remote repository, since I would like to be able to seamlessly transfer the config to a new computer if necessary. However, I don't want the automatic "I can't use these plugins so I'll mark them as disabled" changes made on my mobile device to be pushed to the remote (or even committed at all). At the same time, I would still like to pull changes to those config files from the remote (so that any plugin additions on desktop are brought to mobile, whether they'll be supported or not).

From what I've seen so far, despite many such suggestions, [the Git documentation strongly advises against using `assume-unchanged` and `skip-worktree` flags for this purpose](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files). In addition, pulling changes from the remote would remove the `assume-unchanged` flag or fail with the `skip-worktree` flag. However, it's possible that smudge and clean filters might solve this problem, but I'm not sure how I would do that: I'm thinking that I could rename the relevant desktop config files on pull and push so that they are tracked separately to the 'shared' config.

Any suggestions (which might solve the problem) are welcome. To summarise, the situation is as follows:

- By default, local changes to the config files should be tracked (in some way) such that they can be automatically transferred to other machines
- The Android Obsidian app automatically changes some of the config files upon opening, and these *specific* local changes should **not** be tracked—or at least shouldn't overwrite the information required to reconstruct the 'full' plugin config lists

Comment: Thinking a bit outside the box, could you maybe exclude those config files from git tracking and instead use nextcloud or syncthing to do the synchronization of just those files? I think both of those supports asymentric sync.

Comment: It seems like both of these options require both machines running simultaneously to transfer data between them (i.e. no intermediate cloud storage). Part of the appeal of using a remote GitHub repository is that I can manage my data one device at a time. That said, this might be a good alternative for these recalcitrant files. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I use different config folders: .mobile, .windows, .linux. The last two used to be a single .pc but since I had to specify different ripgrep paths in the Another Quick Switcher plugin, I had to separate the two. In fact, this change was necessitated by how the two OS's handle certain characters used in Hotkeys.

Comment: Ah! I wasn't aware of the config folder over-ride. This would work for my needs, but would mean duplication of any plugins I use on mobile, as well as needing to mirror any changes I make in one to the other, correct? Are you aware of any way to have shared config/partial over-ride?

Comment: You can also change the `isDesktopOnly` flag from manifest.json on the problematic plugins so they are ignored on mobile devices but not disabled.